# Wire mock cloud throwing error for jsonPath.request.body

Tags: mocking, wiremock

I am practicing response template on https://app.wiremock.cloud/mock-apis/; now I am getting:

> [ERROR] 14:7: could not find helper: 'jsonPath.request.body'

```
{{#assign 'uuid'}}{{randomValue length=32 type='ALPHANUMERIC' uppercase=true}}{{/assign}}

{{#if (jsonPath.request.body '$.deviceids')}}

{
"xxxSessionId": "{{xxxSessionId}}",
```

Can you please tell me why its throwing an error?
My logic is that it will return result if there is atlas 1 deviceids present otherwise it will return a blank array.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional in the `if` statement shouldn't be `(jsonPath.request ...)` but `(jsonPath request ...)`. [Look at the example in the documentation here.](https://docs.wiremock.io/response-templating/conditional-logic-and-iteration/#detecting-the-first-and-last-element-while-looping)

```js
...
{{if (jsonPath request.body '$.deviceids')}}
...
```